# Customizing TTSectionedDataSource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, three20

When using the TTSectionedDataSource, each section would be grouped by a white background.

What if I want to change the 2nd section not to use white background, but transparent background, is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is possible. You will have to use custom table cells in your `TTTableViewController`.

You will have to subclass the `TTTableTextItem` and add a `NSString` color parameter and subclass `TTTableTextItemCell`.

Where exactly is your issue?